# Send email at a specific time in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have workflows to send email to the task manager if assigned person delayed to complete the task. The workflow works fine but I wants to send the email at 7:30 A.M. while currently it is sending at 12:00.

[image]

Any help!!

Comment: Kindly check the time-zone as it might possible that due to time-zone, the workflow is not triggering the email at that specified time.

Comment: @DivyaSharma the time zone is correct and proper

Answer (score 0):

You don’t seem to have a setting for 7:30 am (or 8:00 am) in the workflow. The **Comment** action does not act as **Pause until** action.

Here is a sample workflow for your reference:

[image]

In addition, the Workflow local variables for Date/Time store value does not go with the column value.

In my test environment, the variable is using the time zone corresponding to my regional setting while the Date & Time column value is using the time zone UTC (0), so I remove the first condition.

You can use Log to History List action to check if you are using the right Date/Time value to send the email.